# Writing a trigger on a custom object

Tags: triggers, insert, salesforce

I have a field on the contact called `One_Prop_Owned__c`, this is being updated in a view list by a user. Once that is updated and saved, I need a trigger to create a new  object called `Ownership` ie  `McLabs2__Ownership__c`.  There are only two fields that need to be populated.

Is the contact this ownership is being created from. The field on the Ownership form is `McLabs2__Contact__c`,the property field that is entered in the `One_Prop_Owned_c` field.

As you can tell I am pretty green at writing triggers. This below is not working and I am not sure where to go from here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```apex
   trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {
        for (Contact c : Trigger.new){
        McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew= new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
        Contact oldContact = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id);
        if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c != oldContact.One_Prop_Owned__c)
        if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c == null || c.One_Prop_Owned__c == c.One_Prop_Owned__c){
        ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = c.id;
        ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = c.One_Prop_Owned__c;
        insert ownNew;
        }
    }
}
```

Well I was able to fix the trigger, sort of it was workflow I can figure something out. However, I am now having problems writing the test class. This is what I have says that there is 0% coverage for the trigger.

```
@isTest
public class TestOwnership {
    static testMethod void ownershipCreator() {
     McLabs2__Ownership__c ownNew= new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
     ownNew.McLabs2__Contact__c = 'Michael Webb';
     ownNew.McLabs2__Property__c = '131 West 33rd Street';
     insert ownNew;
     }
    }
```

Comment: you can edit your question, please do not add update with code in comments because it's absolutely unreadable

Comment: you just need to insert contact (which is the object where trigger runs) and after that you have to update `One_Prop_Owned__c` field on this record and perform update operation

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```apex
trigger PropOwned on Contact (after update) {
    // create a list of new records which should be inserted in the Database
    List<McLabs2__Ownership__c> ownerships = new List<McLabs2__Ownership__c>();
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id);
        if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c != old.One_Prop_Owned__c) {
            McLabs2__Ownership__c ownership = new McLabs2__Ownership__c();
            // This condition is absolutely unuseful because statement 'c.One_Prop_Owned__c == c.One_Prop_Owned__c' will always return true
            // if (c.One_Prop_Owned__c == null || c.One_Prop_Owned__c == c.One_Prop_Owned__c) {
                ownership.McLabs2__Contact__c  = c.id;
                ownership.McLabs2__Property__c = c.One_Prop_Owned__c;
                ownerships.add(ownership);
            // }
        }
    }
    if ( !ownerships.isEmpty()) { // check that we have records to insert
        insert ownerships;
    }
}
```

If you will got any error with this code please post it as a comment to my answer.

Comment: I did not get any errors, it worked same as mine it added 2 records. I tried to see if there was a workflow or something that was making it run twice, however, there are not workflows and only one other trigger on the contacts.

Comment: @MichaelWebb try to find a reason using debug logs, open a execution tree in developer console and see why the trigger called twice.

Comment: I will try it, I have not used the developer console I'll read up on debugging I found a dreamforce video. Thanks!

Comment: it is a workflow, I deal with that though? I need the workflow to run also?  Thanks! I deactivated 3 of them and it works.

Comment: I found the specific workflow, I guess I will try to re-write it.. This has been a very good learning experience :-) thanks for all your help. If there is another way to get around re-writing the workflow that would be great!